# Append SubKey to DE via Email Lookup

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, integration

We are trying to figure out if this is feasible:

A vendor has a product that triggers a journey, however in their payload, they can only send the email back and the payload is unable to be modified.

Prior, we have overcome this in the past is via Mulesoft integration and doing the lookup in this step. However, the vendor cannot integrate with Mule.

Automations also will not work as the trigger needs to be as near real time as possible.

Comment: a JB api entry would have to contain all the required data to inject into a journey, you would not be able to add this after the fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As EazyE states, Journey Builder API Entry Source is where you already need the subscriberkey.

The only thing you can do is to set up an API layer and check if that is an option for the vendor. If yes, have the vendor not trigger a journey, but send an API call to a custom API endpoint that you set up via cloudpages (with an authentication mechanism). On this custom API endpoint you can accept email as input, lookup subscriberKey by email inside marketing cloud or sales cloud and then, from the custom API, inject the relevant data into the JB API entry source.

This assumes that the email addresses you get as input exist inside the infrastructure as contacts already. If they don't, your custom service could create them. All of the above can be done using the native methods to SFMC (Ampscript, SSJS, WSProxy) on the cloudpage.